# Calling a function and text box from a button

Tags: c#, function, button, linq-to-sql

I have a Windows Form Application. I have a function which uses Linq to SQL to find the records I want but I don't know how to call this function in my button.click event so that the click function will launch my other function.

Also, in my button.click event I will need to set the textBox1.Text value to the sql statement but how would that be done?

Update - Fixed the solution now and here is the completed code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    LinqtoSqlDataContext linqStud = new LinqtoSqlDataContext();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        string city = textBox1.Text;

        searchCity(student, city);
    }

    public Exception searchCity(Student student, string searchCity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCity))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value");
            }
            else
            {
                var City = from stud in linqStud.Students
                           where stud.City == searchCity
                           select stud;

                dataGridView1.DataSource = City;

            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex;
        }
```

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Google v2. We would be very happy to do that for you.

Comment: What exactly do you want the method to do? I doubt you actually meant it to return an `Exception`...are you sure you don't want it to return the `City` variable? What do you want to do with the results from this method? This is not very clear!

Comment: Sorry If I'm not being very clear. All I want to do is call the function to the button's click event so it launches so that the sql is carried out and displayed in the data grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to return an exception from that method. It could use a `void` return type instead. For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Student student = new Student();//set up student obj...
    string city = "Foo";

    searchCity(student, city);
}

public void searchCity(Student student, string searchCity)
{
    //Do your search...
    //set the data source of your gridview

    dataGridView1.DataSource = City;
    dataGridView1.DataBind(); //Make sure you call databind
}
```